# Neo4j: Matching nodes in FOREACH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to merge my assembly to several components using the code below

```
UNWIND $data as row
MERGE (a:Assembly)
ON CREATE SET a+= row
WITH a
UNWIND $components as components
FOREACH(id IN components.uuid | MATCH (c:Component {_uuid: id})
MERGE (a)-[:RECIPE]->(c))
```

However I get an error that doesnt allow match in FOREACH. If I just use merge then I will be creating  new component nodes and not match them to the components that i already have. I am looking for a query that can help me solve this task

Disclaimer: I see a simalar question in overflow but i dont quite understand the answer given as such I put my own problem.

Comment: `MERGE (a:Assembly)` looks buggy. It will match *any* existing `Assembly` node.  So, this query would create *at most* a single `Assemby` node. Can you update your question to state what you are trying to do, and provide your `data` and `components` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use `MATCH` statement in a `FOREACH` clause, you can use the `MERGE` though. If that would work for you it is ok, otherwise you could use a second `UNWIND` statement. Btw.. how come you are using both `UNWIND` and `FOREACH`? Do you have a double nested data structure?

Comment: So you are saying that UNWIND is also considered a nested data. I didnt know that (very new to neo4j). Wouldn't that mean i just have to remove the FOREACH clause as that will be redundant.

Comment: Update I just removed the FOREACH clause and it worked. Thanks for the help Tomaž Bratanič

'''
UNWIND $data as row
MERGE (a:Assembly)
ON CREATE SET a+= row
WITH a
UNWIND $components as components
MATCH (c:Component {_uuid: component.uuid})
MERGE (a)-[:RECIPE]->(c)
'''

Comment: if you found the question helpful, please upvote it or mark it as an answer